# DRY up Ruby ternary

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I often have a situation where I want to do some conditional logic and then return a part of the condition. How can I do this without repeating the part of the condition in the true or false expression?

For example:

```
ClassName.method.blank? ? false : ClassName.method
```

Is there any way to avoid repeating `ClassName.method`?

Here is a real-world example:

```
PROFESSIONAL_ROLES.key(self.professional_role).nil? ? 
    948460516 : PROFESSIONAL_ROLES.key(self.professional_role)
```

Comment: DRY is one of those things that makes a lot of sense when you're repeating blocks of code, or long sequences of chained methods or just doing something that the repetition could be reducing your code quality some how. I don't think it makes sense when you're doing something simple and having to jump through a hoop to become DRY-er. We can easily get seduced into chasing the DRY dragon and lose track of "good enough". In your example, if you're going to loop over it millions of times then add a temp variable or do the `||` thing @sepp2k said, otherwise don't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're okay with `false` being treated the same way as `nil`, you use `||`:

```
PROFESSIONAL_ROLES.key(self.professional_role) || 948460516
```

This will return `948460516` if `key` returns `nil` or `false` and the return value of the call to `key` otherwise.

Note that this will only return 948460516 if `key` returns `nil` or `false`, not if it returns an empty array or string. Since you used `nil?` in your second example, I assume that's okay. However you used `blank?` in the first example (and `blank?` returns `true` for empty arrays and strings), so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to DRY, then you can use a temp variable:

```
x = ClassName.method
x.blank? ? false : x

x = PROFESSIONAL_ROLES.key(self.professional_role)
x.nil? ? 948460516 : x
```

If you don't want to use a temp variable, you can use a block:

```
Proc.new do |x| x.blank? ? false : x end.call(ClassName.method)
Proc.new do |x| x.nil? ? 948460516 : x end.call(PROFESSIONAL_ROLES.key(self.professional_role))
```

For the cases you describe (where you just want to use the original value when a default-check fails), it'd be straightforward to write a helper method:

```
def x_or_default(x, defval, checker = :nil?)
  if x.send(checker) then defval else x end
end
x_or_default(ClassName.method, false, :blank?)
x_or_default(PROFESSIONAL_ROLES.key(self.professional_role), 94840516)
```

which is very similar to the `||` method described, but would also work with your `blank?` example.

I usually use temporary variables for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't look too pretty, but it does make things a bit DRYer.

```
a = "ABC"
b = (temp = a.downcase).length < 3 ? "---" : temp
```

If you don't want to create `temp` variable for whatever reason, you could reuse something that already exists like `$_`.