# Is there a shorter ternary for Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ternary

This is the closest I've found but it deals with booleans instead of numbers:
[DRY up Ruby ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630854/dry-up-ruby-ternary)

I'm trying to avoid a divide by 0 scenario in Ruby, while keeping the code shorter and easier to read.

I want to make the following bit of code more concise:

```
number_to_percentage ((percent_complete.nan? ? 0 : (percent_complete * 100)), :precision => 0)
```

or

```
number_to_percentage ((percent_complete.nan? ? 0 : percent_complete) * 100, :precision => 0)
```

It just seems really hard to read right now. There's more chaining involved so the `percent_complete` is actually quite a bit longer. I'm also returning this value from a method, so it gets longer yet again.

I'd like to avoid using temporary variables or shortening the method names, so was hoping to learn of another way.

If I can avoid having to type "percent_complete" twice then that pretty much solves it.

Comment: Can you change `percent_complete` to end up as `nil` rather than NaN? Then you could exploit `nil.to_i == 0`.

Comment: @mu is too short: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm not sure if I can change it to nil; I'll have to look into that.  Currently, percent_complete is a float divided by a float.

Comment: Personally, on the stylistic front, I'd prefer to not see the ternary statement inside the parameter list to a method.

Comment: @theTinMan: I definitely agree it's hard to read.  I'd love to hear how you style this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just add a custom helper that deals with NaN in the desired way.

```
# in app/helpers/extra_number_helper.rb
module ExtraNumberHelpers
    def number_or_nan_to_percentage(number, options = { })
        number = 0 if(number.respond_to(:nan?) && number.nan?)
        number_to_percentage(number, options)
    end
end
```

Then use `number_or_nan_to_percentage` when you need special NaN handling. This also has the happy side effect of telling the people working on your code that you are explicitly dealing with NaN as a possible value.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  That happy side effect is definitely a big plus.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you define a new method on Numeric?

```
class Numeric
  def safe_to_f
    self.nan? ? 0.0 : self.to_f
  end
end
```

If you like you could also add:

```
class NilClass
  def safe_to_f
    0.0
  end
end
```

Here's another idea:

```
class Object
  # substitute a different object if 'predicate' is true
  # if 'predicate' is :nil?, this is just like ||
  def guard(predicate,substitute)
    send(predicate) ? substitute : self
  end
end
```

Which would allow you to write:

```
percent_complete.guard(:nan?, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was hoping there was something more "built-in"-ish, but that can definitely work.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ALi, this is one of the great things about Ruby -- there are so many ways you can "bend" the language, that you're not stuck with only what comes built-in. Get used to extending the core classes; if you do it well, it's a powerful technique which can make your code more concise and elegant in *many* situations.

Comment: Thanks again for all those great suggestions!  It's hard to decide which one to go with.